# tinyxml. Get full text of node (or "raw content")?

Tags: c++, c, xml, tinyxml

My question differs from others. In other questions people ask how to get a text inside node excluding of inner tags.

For example, I have the following xml:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>
    123
  </tag2>
  <tag3>
    14
  </tag3>
</tag1>
```

If I request a full text in node `tag1` then I should get:

```
<tag2>
  123
</tag2>
<tag3>
  14
</tag3>
```

So is it possible to get this raw content without of iterating all the inner nodes manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ToText()` method or `TiXmlPrinter` class.